# Pull & Insert a HTML signature stored on a server?

Tags: php, html, email, signature

So I have a rather strange question that I've not really been able to find an answer too. But I think I may find the answer here.

I have been tasked with creating a HTML email signature for my company that can be used and displayed on any client. My question; would it be possible to store a html signture on a web server and have a line of code or two that scrapes it from the server and displays it in the email?

A clearer anology of this would be how `<img src="">` works. A image stored on a server is refrenced in the code, retrieved and displayed. Could you do somthing similar but for example, with a whole html page?

The issue I have is that most android email clients either have bad behaviours or simply refuse a signature over a certain character limits.

so if I can pull a page from the web in one or two lines, and have the signature display like normal would this not solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only tag that more or less would load an HTML page on an HTML document would be an `<iframe>` you could stylize to remove the borders. But it's really highly discouraged to use on email [since most mail clients refuse to display them](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/08/do-iframes-work-in-email/).

Wouldn't an image of the signature make the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip. Sadly it wouldn't really. As a team we all use the recognition tools in most librarys to store contact information collected in email signatures. I find it an extreamly useful feature when your conversing with new clients. Using an image would null and void that feature.